# Problem with display function inside circular queue

Tags: c++, data-structures

```
#include <stdio.h>

# define MAX 3
int queue[MAX];  // array declaration
int front=-1;
int rear=-1;
// function to insert an element in a circular queue
void enqueue(int element)
{
    if(front==-1 && rear==-1)   // condition to check queue is empty
    {
        front=0;
        rear=0;
        queue[rear]=element;
    }
    else if((rear+1)%MAX==front)  // condition to check queue is full
    {
        printf("Queue is overflow..");
    }
    else
    {
        rear=(rear+1)%MAX;       // rear is incremented
        queue[rear]=element;     // assigning a value to the queue at the rear position.
    }
}

// function to delete the element from the queue
int dequeue()
{
    if((front==-1) && (rear==-1))  // condition to check queue is empty
    {
        printf("\nQueue is underflow..");
    }
 else if(front==rear)
{
   printf("\nThe dequeued element is %d", queue[front]);
   front=-1;
   rear=-1;
}
else
{
    printf("\nThe dequeued element is %d", queue[front]);
   front=(front+1)%MAX;
}
}
// function to display the elements of a queue
void display()
{
    int i=front;
    if(front==-1 && rear==-1)
    {
        printf("\n Queue is empty..");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nElements in a Queue are :");
        while(i<=rear)
        {
            printf("%d,", queue[i]);
            i=(i+1)%MAX;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int choice=1,x;   // variables declaration

    while(choice<4 && choice!=0)   // while loop
    {
    printf("\nPress 1: Insert an element");
    printf("\nPress 2: Delete an element");
    printf("\nPress 3: Display the element");
    printf("\nEnter your choice");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    switch(choice)
    {

        case 1:

        printf("Enter the element which is to be inserted");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        enqueue(x);
        break;
        case 2:
        dequeue();
        break;
        case 3:
        display();

    }}
    return 0;
}
```

I have problem with display function how can i print all element if rear can be in somecases less than front for example in this code i  try to enqueue 3 elements 1,2,3 then dequeue two elements which i mean here 1,2 after that i try to enque two elements 1,2 again finaly when i try to display elements i get nothing so what is the perfect way to display queue elements

Comment: Unrelated: this `# define max 3` macro can produce untold havoc. At the very least uppercase the sucker `# define MAX 3` to avoid accidentally turning stuff like `std::max` into `std::3`

Comment: @user4581301 done

Comment: `while(i<=rear)` should be `do ... while(i != (rear+1)%MAX)`

Comment: `int dequeue()` promises to return an `int` but doesn't, and this will result in the dreaded [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) and an invalid program. You probably want `void dequeue()`.

Comment: Further explanation of @Azrael3000 's point: Because a circular buffer wraps around  it is very easy to have a `rear` that is earlier in the backing array than the `front`.

Comment: Well I can only recommend you to use a debugger and step through the code, it's an important skill to learn and will help you greatly in the future

Comment: else
    {
        printf("\nElements in a Queue are :");
        do
        {
            printf("%d,", queue[i]);
            i=(i+1)%MAX;
        }
        while(i != (rear+1)%MAX);
    } is that right or what ??| @Azrael3000

Comment: I'm not sure that a `do/while` is the right way to go because `do/while` always executes at least once, and that's a bad thing to do if `front == rear` and the queue is empty.

Comment: so can we just use while or that will cause problem @user4581301

Comment: This is not correct @user4581301, front==rear does not mean the queue is empty according to his code. It means there is one element, that's why do while is the way to go.

Comment: @Azrael3000 look at all the extra code used in order to almost get that approach working and regardless of what is empty test is used, you'll still have a problem with `do/while` and an empty queue.

Comment: I agree the whole thing could be done more efficiently as shown in your answer. I just wanted to show how to correct his original code. It is working minus that little detail in the display function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... here's a working solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>

# define MAX 3

class CircularQueue
{

private:
    int queue[MAX];  // array declaration
    int front;
    int rear;

public:
    CircularQueue() :
        front(-1),
        rear(-1)
    { }

    // function to insert an element in a circular queue
    void enqueue(int element)
    {
        if(front==-1 && rear==-1)   // condition to check queue is empty
        {
            front=0;
            rear=0;
            queue[rear]=element;
        }
        else if((rear+1)%MAX==front)  // condition to check queue is full
        {
            printf("Queue is overflow..\n");
        }
        else
        {
            rear=(rear+1)%MAX;       // rear is incremented
            queue[rear]=element;     // assigning a value to the queue at the rear position.
        }
    }

    // function to delete the element from the queue
    void dequeue()
    {
        if((front==-1) && (rear==-1))  // condition to check queue is empty
        {
            printf("Queue is underflow..\n");
        }
        else if(front==rear)
        {
            printf("The dequeued element is %d\n", queue[front]);
            front=-1;
            rear=-1;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("The dequeued element is %d\n", queue[front]);
            front=(front+1)%MAX;
        }
    }

    // function to display the elements of a queue
    void display()
    {
        if(front==-1 && rear==-1)
            printf("Queue is empty..\n");
        else
        {
            printf("Elements in a Queue are: ");
            int i=front;
            do
            {
                if (i != front)
                    printf(",");
                printf("%d", queue[i]);
                i=(i+1)%MAX;
            } while (i != (rear+1)%MAX);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    CircularQueue cq;

    unsigned int choice=1;   // variables declaration

    while(choice<4 && choice!=0)   // while loop
    {
        printf("Press 1: Insert an element\n");
        printf("Press 2: Delete an element\n");
        printf("Press 3: Display the element\n");
        printf("Press any other number to exit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch(choice)
        {

        case 1:
            printf("Enter the element which is to be inserted: ");
            int x;
            scanf("%d", &x);
            cq.enqueue(x);
            break;
        case 2:
            cq.dequeue();
            break;
        case 3:
            cq.display();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I made a couple of changes to the output, see the positions of the `\n`. Its always good to give the next print statement a new line to write to if the current output is complete.

The biggest change, I put everything in a class. That way you don't have any global variables, which is to 99.999% a bad thing. Your code is very C like, so normally I would use `std::cout` as well and with `std::vector` you could easily make you buffer have arbitrary size.

Here's some output:

```
Press 1: Insert an element
Press 2: Delete an element
Press 3: Display the element
Press any other number to exit
Enter your choice: 1
Enter the element which is to be inserted: 2
Press 1: Insert an element
Press 2: Delete an element
Press 3: Display the element
Press any other number to exit
Enter your choice: 3
Elements in a Queue are: 2
Press 1: Insert an element
Press 2: Delete an element
Press 3: Display the element
Press any other number to exit
Enter your choice: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR version: The hard part of making a circular buffer is telling the full condition from the empty condition because they are both `front == rear` unless you take extra steps like tracking the size or maintaining a `bool full;` or preventing `rear` from catching up to `front`.

I like the latter approach because it makes for really simple code. I like writing simple code. You don't have to think as hard debugging it. You don't have to spend as much time writing it. You don't get bothered by the maintenance team supporting it. Simple code is only a problem when it's too simple and misses a case.

So I'm going for simple here.

Embedding comments where I feel it's appropriate because explanation is easier to understand when it's right up close to what it is explaining.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>


// made MAX one bigger
// If we waste a space in the queue the only time front can be the same as rear 
// is if the queue is empty. No ambiguity. No special code for special cases or 
// extra tracking variables to tell full from empty.
// All for the low, low price of one queue element.
# define MAX 4
// in full on c++ this would be constexpr int MAX = 4;
// In general avoid macros because they are really stupid. With a macro any 
// token MAX will be replaced with 4 no matter how bad an idea it is. The 
// resulting compiler errors get really weird.
// with a constexpr, the compiler will not substitute anything and will take 
// context into account, giving much better diagnostics if you screw up

int queue[MAX]; // array declaration
                // Don't comment the obvious stuff
                // it just clutters up the code and makes you look... well..
                // Hey, look! Dummy here needs a comment to rem'ber he's 
                // defining an array! HA HA HA HA HA!
                // You've got better things to do than put up with smurf like that.
int front=0;
int rear=0;
// global variables suck. Because a global can be changed by anything at any 
// time tracking errors is a pain in the neck. Every function could have 
// unexpected side effects and needs to be examined while debugging.  

// Plus because these variables are global and shared, you can only ever have 
// ONE queue and EVERYBODY can use it.

// These variables and the queue-handling functions should be in a queue class, 
// and there should be an instance of this class defined in main.


// helper functions to keep repetition down.
// Also a well-named helper makes what's happening brutally obvious to anyone 
// reading the code
int advance(int pos)
{
    return (pos+1)%MAX;
}

bool empty()
{
    return front == rear;
}

bool full()
{
    return front == advance(rear);
    // because of the wasted space telling full from empty is dead easy 
}

// function to insert an element in a circular queue
void enqueue(int element)
{
    if(full()) // see? Much easer to read than if (front == (rear+1)%MAX)
               // now we barely need to comment.
    {
        printf("Queue is overflow.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        queue[rear]=element;     
        rear = advance(rear);
    }
}

// function to delete the element from the queue
void dequeue()
{
    if(empty())
    {
        printf("Queue is underflow.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The dequeued element is %d\n", queue[front]);
        front = advance(front);
    }
}

// function to display the elements of a queue
void display()
{
    if(empty())
    {
        printf("Queue is empty.");
    }
    else
    {
        int i = front;
        printf("Elements in a Queue are :");
        while(i!=rear)
        {
            printf("%d,", queue[i]);
            i = advance(i);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

// test the logic in small chunks. Make sure the queue works perfectly before 
// slapping in a menu system. If there's a bug, you don't have to ask if it's 
// in the menu or in the queue because you're only testing one thing at a time
// when you know they both work separately, put 'em together and test again 
// just to be on the safe side.
int main()
{
    display();
    enqueue(1);
    display();
    dequeue();
    display();
    enqueue(2);
    display();
    enqueue(3);
    display();
    enqueue(4);
    display();
    enqueue(5); // fail
    display();
    enqueue(6); // fail
    display();
    dequeue();
    display();
    dequeue();
    display();
    dequeue();
    display();
    dequeue(); // fail
    display();
    dequeue(); // fail
    display();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no need for the full flag. You can always set front or rear to -1, for example.